# PYTHON how to search a text file for a number

Tags: python, search, repeat

There's a text file that I'm reading line by line. It looks something like this:

3

3

67

46

67

3

46

Each time the program encounters a new number, it writes it to a text file. The way I'm thinking of doing this is writing the first number to the file, then looking at the second number and checking if it's already in the output file. If it isn't, it writes THAT number to the file. If it is, it skips that line to avoid repetitions and goes on to the next line. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking output file for the number if it was already written it is better to keep this information in a variable (a `set` or `list`). It will save you on disk reads.

To search a file for numbers you need to loop through each line of that file, you can do that with `for line in open('input'):` loop, where `input` is the name of your file. On each iteration `line` would contain one line of input file ended with end of line character '\n'.

In each iteration you should try to convert the value on that line to a number, `int()` function may be used. You may want to protect yourself against empty lines or non-number values with `try` statement.

In each iteration having the number you should check if the value you found wasn't already written to the output file by checking a `set` of already written numbers. If value is not in the set yet, add it and write to the output file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                           
numbers = set() # create a set for storing numbers that were already written       
out = open('output', 'w') # open 'output' file for writing                      
for line in open('input'): # loop through each line of 'input' file             
    try:                                                                        
        i = int(line) # try to convert line to integer                          
    except ValueError:  # if conversion to integer fails display a warning         
        print "Warning: cannot convert to number string '%s'" % line.strip()       
        continue # skip to next line on error                                   
    if i not in numbers: # check if the number wasn't already added to the set  
        out.write('%d\n' % i) # write the number to the 'output' file followed by EOL
        numbers.add(i) # add number to the set to mark it as already added
```

This example assumes that your `input` file contains single numbers on each line. In case of empty on incorrect line a warning will be displayed to `stdout`.

You could also use `list` in the above example, but it may be less efficient.
Instead of `numbers = set()` use `numbers = []` and instead of `numbers.add(i)`: `numbers.append(i)`. The if condition stays the same.

Comment: Giving a person a fish is far less valuable than teaching how to fish. Also, silently ignoring exceptions is something that most fish should not do.

Comment: @msw After adding the initial code there were already three far better answers, so I didn't bother to enhance mine. But your comment motivated me to make it a bit better. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 5):

Rather than searching your output file, keep a set of the numbers you've written, and only write numbers that are not in the set.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. Use a `set()` to keep track of all the numbers you have seen. It will only have one of each.

```
numbers = set()
for line in open("numberfile"):
    numbers.add(int(line.strip()))
open("outputfile", "w").write("\n".join(str(n) for n in numbers))
```

Note this reads them all, then writes them all out at once. This will put them in a different order than in the original file (assuming they're integers, they will come out in ascending numeric order). If you don't want that, you can also write them as you read them, but only if they are not already in the set:

```
numbers = set()
with open("outfile", "w") as outfile:
    for line in open("numberfile"):
        number = int(line.strip())
        if number not in numbers:
            outfile.write(str(number) + "\n")
            numbers.add(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with exceptionally large files?  You probably don't want to try to "search" the file you're writing to for a value you just wrote.  You (probably) want something more like this:

```
encountered = set([])

with open('file1') as fhi, open('file2', 'w') as fho:
  for line in fhi:
    if line not in encountered:
      encountered.add(line)
      fho.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scan through a file to see if it contains a number on any line, you could do something like this:

```
def file_contains(f, n):
    with f:
        for line in f:
            if int(line.strip()) == n:
                return True

        return False
```

However as Ned points out in his answer, this isn't a very efficient solution; if you have to search through the file again for each line, the running time of your program will increase proportional to the square of the number of numbers.

It the number of values is not incredibly large, it would be more efficient to use a set ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set)). Sets are designed to very efficiently keep track of unordered values. For example:

```
with open("input_file.txt", "rt") as in_file:
    with open("output_file.txt", "wt") as out_file:
        encountered_numbers = set()
        for line in in_file:
            n = int(line.strip())

            if n not in encountered_numbers:
                encountered_numbers.add(n)
                out_file.write(line)
```